# How to get the Main folder and Subfolder name in java

Tags: java

I am using `Files.walk` function to get the files present in a sub directory of a main directory. for example :

```
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar1/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar1/myfiles.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar2/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar3/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar4/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar5/
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar6/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar7/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar8/myfile.sql
/path/to/stuff/foo/bar9/myfile.sql
```

this is my code :

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/stuff")).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                buildFiles();
            }
            });
```

in the buildFiles i need to get the filename and the subfoldername and make that as a file name example loop 1 : `path=/path/to/stuff/foo/bar1/myfile.sql` and the filename should be `foo_bar1.sql`. How would i do that?

Comment: You've tried to print `cmd` array to see if it looks exactly the same if you put it on the console?

Comment: thanks for the idea. its working now.

Comment: If it works now, just ask for close the question :)

Comment: you have not declared the value variable that is supposed to show the result

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a file using the path. That will help you to manage your file. I guess you wonder if creating a file with

> new file()

won't overwrite your file. Don't worry it won't It will help to have some sort of java reference to your file.

```
    Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/stuff")).forEach(filePath -> {
                     if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath1)) {
                     File file1 = new File(filePath1);
                     String folderName = file.getName();
                     Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/stuff"+folderName)).forEach(filePath2 -> {
                           if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath2)) {
                           File file2 = new File(filePath2);
                           String subFolderName = file2.getName();
                           String result = folderName+subFolderName+".sql";
                           builFiles(result)
                          }
                     });
                  }
               });
```

Comment: This wont work. I need the file name to be `foo_bar1.sql` from one the path : `/path/to/stuff/foo/bar1/myfile.sql` 
The function `buildFiles()` was precisely for that reason but i was not able to come up with a easy logic.

Comment: Is there any way to get the last two subfolder names.

Comment: Ok I can see what you desire. I think you can get the first folder then you keep it name in a variable, after that, you search that folder and you catch the element(folder) that it contains and get it name, that you concatenate with the first folder name and you add the extention .sql. Actually try to look my answer I've just edited it I hope I've now understood what you mean